# How to fetch details of user who created an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can I fetch the details of the user who created the instance in AWS using

- instance-id
- ami id
- tag details
- or anything?

I want to contact the person who created a particular instance under a particular role. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look at CloudTrail logs. Search by Instance id (resource name) and RunInstances (Event name)

Comment: Do you alread have the instance created or do you want an easy way to have this information? Indeed CloudTrail and tagging are your best bets here

Comment: @gusto2 instance is already created. i need to find who created it; the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query CloudTrail logs to find the user who started the instances.

Here is the Python Boto3 script I have created to list all the instances and owner.

https://gist.github.com/sudharsans/39d5eaf8a82b7ccdf8b3230d13ba7d81

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Cloudtrail events, and if you need more derailed info. then you can make use of AWS Config which will give you even granular details